# Using foreach inside of a defined array PHP

Tags: php

Is there anyway to loop through an array and insert each instance into another array?

```
   $aFormData = array(
        'x_show_form' => 'PAYMENT_FORM',
        foreach($aCartInfo['items'] as $item){
            'x_line_item' => $item['id'].'<|>'.$item['title'].'<|>'.$item['description'].'<|>'.$item['quantity'].'<|>'.$item['price'].'<|>N',
        }

    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly in the array declaration, but you could do the following:

```
$aFormData = array(
    'x_show_form' => 'PAYMENT_FORM',
    'x_line_item' => array(),
);
foreach($aCartInfo['items'] as $item){
    $aFormData['x_line_item'][] = $item['id'].'<|>'.$item['title'].'<|>'.$item['description'].'<|>'.$item['quantity'].'<|>'.$item['price'].'<|>N';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way ; but you must go in two steps :

- First, create your array with the static data
- And, then, dynamically add more data

In your case, you'd use something like this, I suppose :

```
$aFormData = array(
   'x_show_form' => 'PAYMENT_FORM',
   'x_line_item' => array(),  // right now, initialize this item to an empty array
);

foreach($aCartInfo['items'] as $item){
    // Add the dynamic value based on the current item
    // at the end of $aFormData['x_line_item']
    $aFormData['x_line_item'][] = $item['id'] . '<|>' . $item['title'] . '<|>' . $item['description'] . '<|>' . $item['quantity'] . '<|>' . $item['price'] . '<|>N';
}
```

And, of course, you should read the [section of the manual that deals with **arrays**][1] : it'll probably help you a lot ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this :

```
$aFormData = array(
    'x_show_form' => 'PAYMENT_FORM',
    'x_line_item' => array(),
);

foreach($aCartInfo['items'] as $item) {
     $aFormData['x_line_item'][] = implode('<|>', $aCartInfo['items']).'<|>N',
}
```